# Textboxes in Linux-based systems

Tags: linux, emacs, user-interface, key-binding, gtk

I know this is a very wide-ranging question, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

For a long time now, I have been really frustrated with the fact that textboxes in my Linux distros (I have Ubuntu and CentOS) use Windows like keyboard shortcuts (End, Home, Arrow Keys) instead of Emacs ones (`C-a`, `C-e`, `C-f`, `C-b`, `C-p`, `C-n`). Textboxes in Mac on the other hand seem to allow using both. I tried some tools to change this, like `AutoKey`, but they are very slow and make editing somewhat clumsy.

I decided that I would instead look into the source code of my tools to see how hard it would be to change the keybinding in textboxes. I thought at first that I should be modifying `Gtk` to change the keybinding in the text boxes. However, I am no longer sure since I don't think web browsers (like Firefox which I am using right now to type this message) use Gtk textboxes. Although, I am not sure which keybindings work on Firefox textboxes under Mac (I don't have access to a Mac).

So my question is: What do you think is the correct level (software library) at which to make this change to make sure that the whole system adopts the new keybindings. Would I have to change both Gtk and my web browser (Firefox) separately?

Any pointers or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a program like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) to capture your Emacs hotkeys and put out Windows-style ones?

Comment: @Mokubai, AutoHotKey is for Windows. I tried using AutoKey for linux (among others), but they were very slow (even 0.5s delay could be annoying here) and made editing long text clumsy.

Comment: Have you googled "emacs key bindings for firefox".  I find this:  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_(Firefox) and this:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/emacs-keybinding

Comment: Unfortunately, the first link is outdated in the new firefox and the extension if for browsing rather than text editing. In any case, thanks for the links. They gave me quite a few pointers to start from.